# send header with put request node.js

Tags: json, node.js, rest, request

```
var request=require('request');

var values = [
  {
    "id": "24",
    "kind": "nature",
    "data": {}
  }
]

request.put("http://localhost:5000/api/article/",values,function (err,data,res) {
        res=JSON.parse(res)
        console.log(res)
    })
```

I think it's kinda obvious what I'm trying to do here. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?? If I'm verry far of can someone set me on the right track?

Comment: [headers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers) check out this

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = require('request');
var values = [
  {
    "id": "24",
    "kind": "nature",
    "data": {}
  }
];
request({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/article/',
  body: values,
  json: true,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
}, (err, res, body) => {
  // ...
});
```

See the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers